# Endless recursion when trying to save an entity in a many-to-many relation In spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to build an application which handles courses and students. The relation between them is many-to-many. My intention is if I have a list of students and a list of courses, I want to add those students to every course.

I do not understand why this is not happening, as I have defined everything ok.

```
public class User {
...
@JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_course",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
    private Set<Course> courses;@JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_course",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
    private Set<Course> courses;
...
}
```

```
public class Course {
...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    private Set<User> students;
...
}
```

Now, this is the function which is causing my issues. Its mechanism is simple: for each course, check if the user exists and if yes and is a student, add it to the course student list:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<String> allocateCoursesToStudents(AllocateCoursesToStudents allocateCoursesToStudents) {
        for (int i = 0; i < allocateCoursesToStudents.getCourseSlugs().size(); i++) {
            Optional<Course> course = coursesRepository.findBySlug(allocateCoursesToStudents.getCourseSlugs().get(i));
            if (course.isEmpty())
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);

            for (int j = 0; j < allocateCoursesToStudents.getUserSlugs().size(); j++) {
                Optional<User> user = userRepository.findBySlug(allocateCoursesToStudents.getUserSlugs().get(j));
                if(user.isEmpty())
                    continue;

                if(user.get().getRole().getName() != UserRolesEnum.ROLE_STUDENT)
                    continue;

                course.get().getStudents().add(user.get());
            }

        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? If i put only `course.get().getStudents().add(user.get());`, then it produces no modifications in the DB, but if I put `user.get().getCourses().add(course.get());`, then it produces a stackoverflow error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at ro.adfaber.codeschoolsclubs.models.Role$HibernateProxy$Q1UVJJnB.hashCode(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
    at ro.adfaber.codeschoolsclubs.models.User.hashCode(User.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at ro.adfaber.codeschoolsclubs.models.Course.hashCode(Course.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:459) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at ro.adfaber.codeschoolsclubs.models.User.hashCode(User.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
```

In general how to handle JPA Persistance? Why is this happening here?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem really related to your actual question. Please make sure your title summarizes your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StackoverflowError JPA in OneToMany relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482449/stackoverflowerror-jpa-in-onetomany-relationship)

Comment: @RobSpoor It did not worked

Comment: have you looked at: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Comment: @TasteMyBomb then convert your entities into DTOs (records can make this easy) that do not have the bidirectional relation. Because it's this relation that's causing your issue - if a user is serialized, all of its courses are serialized, and for each course all of its users. This continues until the error is thrown because Jackson keeps encountering the same objects.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JPA - check the stack trace. It shows Course.hashCode calling User.hashCode calling Role.hashCode. You have your own endless recursive loop because you have put in relationships in your hashcode calculations. Since you don't even know you've done it, I'd bet you are using Lombok and let it generate the hashcode, equals and likely toString causing useless code. Remove them and your issue will go away. PS your question states "I have defined everything ok"; assumptions like that cause you to leave out aspects from investigation or look clearly at what you have

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want implement api which binds courses to given users.
So I suggest to use many-to-many relationship with extra entity between User and Course entities, then you can bind course with user by creating new row in extra table.
I suggest use of DTOs in data transfer.
In your case, this API would probably be implemented as follows:

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  //other fiels
}
```

Course entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course{
  @Id
  private Long id;
  //other fields
}
```

Extra Table between entities UserCourse:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_courses")
public class UserCourse {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
  private Course course;
}
```

You can create instance of UserCourse by given ids.

- In this case you can use binding fields like 'enrolled_date'
- And you can use Embadded Id istead of Long id for UserCourse, it uses combination of user and course ids as primary key in users_courses table.